Not Receiving Emails with Nodemailer despite Successful Response
I'm having trouble with my Node.js application where I'm using Nodemailer to send emails through a contact form. The request seems to be processing correctly, and I'm getting a successful response from the Nodemailer sendMail method, but I'm not receiving any emails in my inbox.
Setup:
Backend: Node.js with Express and Nodemailer
Email Service: Gmail (using SMTP)
Environment: Local development on localhost
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const app = express();

// CORS Middleware
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    credentials: true,
}));

// Middleware
app.use(express.json());

// Nodemailer setup
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
        pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS
    }
});

// Contact Form API endpoint
app.post('/api/contact', (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, message } = req.body;

    const mailOptions = {
        from: email,
        to: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
        subject: `Contact Form Submission from ${name}`,
        text: message
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error("Error sending mail: ", error);
            return res.status(500).send(error.toString());
        }
        console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
        res.status(200).send('Message sent: ' + info.response);
    });
});

// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));


What I've Tried:
Verified that process.env.EMAIL_USER and process.env.EMAIL_PASS are set correctly.
Tested with hardcoded email values to rule out issues with form data.
Checked the spam/junk folder for the emails.
Used Postman to send a test request and received a successful response (Message sent: 250 2.0.0 OK).
Question: Despite receiving a success message from Nodemailer, I'm not getting any emails. Are there any common pitfalls or additional settings I should check to resolve this issue? Any insights or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated!

The issue is in POST endpoint. The createTransport function is set up for process.env.EMAIL_USER while you are assiging this to "to". process.env.EMAIL_USER should go to "from" attribute and the email from body should go to "to" attribute.
 //fix
 const mailOptions = {
        from: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
        to: email,
        subject: `Contact Form Submission from ${name}`,
        text: message
    };


Thank you for the suggestion! I applied the fix (from: process.env.EMAIL_USER and to: email), but I'm still facing the issue. The mail isn't sent, and the POST request doesn't appear in the network tab.
Any further suggestions would be great!

If the POST request doesn't appear in the network, then there must be something wrong with the frontend, can you provide more detail code.

https://github.com/jyoti-ranj/Portfolio-Website/blob/master/src/components/ContactForm.js just see whether you are able to access or not???
